# How do I get the HTTPServletRequest in Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

To get the request URL, found below approaches in stack overflow.

1st approach:

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

public void getURL(){
String url=request.getRequestURL().toString();
}
```

2nd approach:

```
public void getURL(){
String url=ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().toUriString();
}
```

3rd approach:

```
public void getURL(){
HttpServletRequest request= 
((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
String url=request.getRequestURL().toString();
}
```

I am confused which one to use to get the request URL in the spring boot application.

if i go with 3rd approach, then should i need to create bean of RequestContextListener in Configuration class as shown below?

```
@Bean
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

Comment: What are you going to do with request? If you need to validate for each request you can create a filter that httpservletrequest is already in.

Comment: I need to validate each request and based on the url I have to call two different methods.

Comment: Just look at filters in spring when you define filter with onceperrequest you have request object and you can validate it

Comment: The above approaches looks easier to implement... can i make use of any one of them to retrieve and validate the request?

Comment: Sure you can use that way

Comment: please suggest better to go with which approach from above.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very simple. Create a class that is annotated as `@RestController` and in it create a method that is handling your mapping. In that method list `HttpServletRequest request` as your parameter. That's it, in this method you will get it as parameter and can use it. Below is one of my working examples that does just that.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class UploadTestController {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadTest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            String lengthStr = request.getHeader("content-length");
            int length = TextUtils.parseStringToInt(lengthStr, -1);
            if(length > 0) {
                byte[] buff = new byte[length];
                ServletInputStream sis =request.getInputStream();
                int counter = 0;
                while(counter < length) {
                    int chunkLength = sis.available();
                    byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkLength];
                    sis.read(chunk);
                    for(int i = counter, j= 0; i < counter + chunkLength; i++, j++) {
                        buff[i] = chunk[j];
                    }
                    counter += chunkLength;
                    if(counter < length) {
                        TimeUtils.sleepFor(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    }
                }
                Files.write(Paths.get("C:\\Michael\\tmp\\testPic.jpg"), buff);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(TextUtils.getStacktrace(e));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In springboot, if use are using @Restcontroller, HttpServletRequest already exist in first paramester of controler method

```
@PostMapping(value = "/abc")
public ResponseEntity<?> abcMethod(HttpServletRequest req){
   // Do anything with HttpServletRequest here
}
```